# How to extract licence plate from black and white picture

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I got this homework where I have to extract a licence plate from pictures of cars. I don't have to identify the plate numbers and letters(that is a colleague's job). I have to do it in Matlab. I already did the plate identification part, but now I can't understand how to extract correctly the licence plate part from the picture.

You can see in the image bellow what I have done until now:
[image]

Now I don't know how do I crop the white part and moreover it should be something like this:
[image]

What I mean is that it should be rotated so that it gets to a horizontal position.

This is a project that needs to be done by two people. The first one(me) has to give the second only the licence plate from any sorts of images and the second one has to use OCR. This is what the professor asked.

I am out of ideas. The answer is probably simple, but I ave worked all day and I can't find a solution.

Comment: I have solved it! I can't believe how simple it was. The black and white image is a matrix that has 0 where it is black and 1 where it is white. So the solution is just some 0 and 1 searching. I promise to post the full code here when it will all be finished and clean :)

Comment: So, erm, I guess the code isn't clean yet ? :)

Comment: :)) for the "erm" . Yes, I have to present it tomorrow so I haven't worked on it since that day. I posted the code, a lot more cleaned than it was in that day, but it still needs work :)

Answer (score 2):

Note: The Variables are in a different language, but I believe the code is readable as it is. I am sorry, but I don't have time at the moment to work on it :(

Now this algorithm is not the best, but is a starting point. I don't have the time to work on it now, but it can surely by improved. For example, as it can be seen in the images at the bottom the licence plate place is filled very nicely, but in some pictures the last line of white pixels doesn't have the same length as the ones above and so you can end up with just half of the licence plate. One solution can be: right before getting the corners of the licence plate make all white lines the same length(with the length of the longest line)

```
BW = edge(rgb2gray(imagine), 'canny');

    %# hough transform
    [H T R] = hough(BW);
    P  = houghpeaks(H, 4, 'threshold',ceil(0.75*max(H(:))));
    lines = houghlines(BW, T, R, P);

    % shearing transformata
    slopes = vertcat(lines.point2) - vertcat(lines.point1);
    slopes = slopes(:,2) ./ slopes(:,1);
    TFORM = maketform('affine', [1 -slopes(1) 0 ; 0 1 0 ; 0 0 1]);
    imagine2 = imtransform(imagine, TFORM);

    %# show image with lines overlayed, and the aligned/rotated image
    axes(handles.ImagineRotita)
    imshow(imagine2); 

    imagineGrey = rgb2gray(imagine2);

%-----------------------------------------------------------------

    axes(handles.ImaginePrel1)
    imshow(imagineGrey);

    imagineFiltrata = medfilt2(imagineGrey,[3 3]);
    axes(handles.ImagineFilt)
    imshow(imagineFiltrata);

    SE = strel('disk',1);
    GrayDil = imdilate(imagineGrey,SE);
    GrayEr = imerode(imagineGrey,SE);
    gdiff = imsubtract(GrayDil,GrayEr);
    gdiff = mat2gray(gdiff);
    gdiff = conv2(gdiff,[1 1;1 1]);
    gdiff = imadjust(gdiff,[0.5 0.7],[0 1],0.1);

    B = logical(gdiff);
    er = imerode(B,strel('line',50,0));
    out1 = imsubtract(B,er);

    imagineSobel = imfill(out1,'holes');

    H = bwmorph(imagineSobel,'thin',1);
    H = imerode(H,strel('line',3,90));

    final = bwareaopen(H,100);

    Iprops = regionprops(final,'BoundingBox','Image');

    axes(handles.ImagineSobel)
    imshow(final);

    imagineCuratata = imclearborder(final,18);
    imagineCuratata = bwareaopen(imagineCuratata,200);
    axes(handles.ImagineSobelEd)
    imshow(imagineCuratata);

    fileID = fopen('ImagineRezultata.txt','wb');
    dlmwrite('ImagineRezultata.txt',imagineCuratata);
    fclose('all');

    imagineCuratata2 = imagineCuratata;

    [dimX,dimY] = size(imagineCuratata2);

%-----------------------------------------------------------------
%-----------The licence plate is filled with white pixels---------
PrimPixelAlbStanga = 0;
PrimPixelAlbDreapta = 0;
Flag = 0;

for i = 1:dimX
    for j = 1:dimY
        if Flag == 0
            if imagineCuratata2(i,j) == 1
                PrimPixelAlbStanga = j;
                Flag = 1;
            end
        end
        if Flag == 1
            if imagineCuratata2(i,j) == 1
                PrimPixelAlbDreapta = j;
            end
        end
    end
    if PrimPixelAlbStanga > 0
        for k = PrimPixelAlbStanga:PrimPixelAlbDreapta
            imagineCuratata2(i,k) = 1;
        end
    end
    PrimPixelAlbStanga = 0;
    PrimPixelAlbDreapta = 0;
    Flag = 0;
end

%-----------------------------------------------------------------

%-----------------------------------------------------------------
%----------The smaller lines with white pixels are removed--------
%----------this is to eliminate all the smaller lines that--------
%--------------remained for example the logo sometimes------------

PrimPixelAlbStanga = 0;
PrimPixelAlbDreapta = 0;
Flag = 0;

for i = 1:dimX
    for j = 1:dimY
        if Flag == 0
            if imagineCuratata2(i,j) == 1
                PrimPixelAlbStanga = j;
                Flag = 1;
            end
        end
        if Flag == 1
            if imagineCuratata2(i,j) == 1
                PrimPixelAlbDreapta = j;
            end
        end
    end
    if PrimPixelAlbStanga > 0
        if (PrimPixelAlbDreapta - PrimPixelAlbStanga) < 40
            for k = PrimPixelAlbStanga:PrimPixelAlbDreapta
                imagineCuratata2(i,k) = 0;
            end
        end
    end
    PrimPixelAlbStanga = 0;
    PrimPixelAlbDreapta = 0;
    Flag = 0;
end

axes(handles.ImagineCropata)
imshow(imagineCuratata2);

%-----------------------------------------------------------------

%-----------------------------------------------------------------
%---------the corners of the licence plate are determined---------

imagineCuratata2 = bwareaopen(imagineCuratata2,500);

PrimaCoordX = 0;
PrimaCoordY = 0;
UltimaCoordX = 0;
UltimaCoordY = 0;
determinat = 0;

for i = 1:dimX
    for j = 1:dimY
        if imagineCuratata2(i,j) == 1
            if determinat == 0
                PrimaCoordX = j;
                PrimaCoordY = i;
                determinat = 1;
            else
                            UltimaCoordX = j;
                            UltimaCoordY = i;
            end            
        end
    end
end

PrimaCoordColX = 0;
PrimaCoordColY = 0;
UltimaCoordColX = 0;
UltimaCoordColY = 0;
determinatCol = 0;

for j = 1:dimY
    for i = 1:dimX
        if imagineCuratata2(i,j) == 1
            if determinatCol == 0
                PrimaCoordColX = j;
                PrimaCoordColY = i;
                determinatCol = 1;
            else                
                    UltimaCoordColX = j;
                    UltimaCoordColY = i;
            end            
        end
    end
end

    xmin = 0;
    ymin = 0;
    width = 0;
    height = 0;

    if PrimaCoordX < dimX/2
        xmin = PrimaCoordX;
        ymin = PrimaCoordY;
    else 
        xmin = PrimaCoordColX;
        ymin = PrimaCoordY;
    end

    xmin = xmin - xmin * 0.1;
    ymin = ymin * 1.1;

    if PrimaCoordX < dimX/2
        width = UltimaCoordX - PrimaCoordX;
        height = UltimaCoordY - PrimaCoordY;
    else
        width = UltimaCoordColX - PrimaCoordColX;
        height = UltimaCoordY - PrimaCoordY;
    end

    rect = [xmin ymin abs(width) abs(height)];

    RezultatCropat = imcrop(imagine2, rect);

    axes(handles.ImagineCropataSiFilt)
    imshow(RezultatCropat);

end
```

The results of what I did can be seen in these pictures:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing, the results look really good. I can only suggest to divide the code into logical parts, e.g. one function for pre-processing of the image, another for search of the plate corners at the pre-processed image, separate methods for region extraction and post-processing. It is a good practice in general, and in particular later you might want to retry to extract the plate region with minor parameters variations if OCR fails.

Answer (score 0):

If you're taking a route of trying to physically manipulate the image to create the final *flattened* representation from any number of angled originals, that is probably not the way to proceed.

If you have defined the logic to identify the plate boundaries, then you should be able to snap that, then run it through an OCR application.  That will give you the text, then you can just create a flat image with that text.

Now if you have to capture any graphics from the plate as well, you'll need to track down a database of all possible graphic images, and then code a comparison/matching routine, such that you can identify the license plate graphics, but then use your "flat" version from the database, to create the flattened image, that you then output your OCR'd text onto.

For example, I scraped down just the license plate, and doing a search on images.google.com (using their "search by image" functionality, I found a good many ["flattened" versions of the image](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&tbs=simg:CAESZRpjCxCo1NgEGgIICgwLELCMpwgaPAo6CAISFN8I3gvIFOAIwgjrFIQMzRbaDN8LGiBGvuo1uoCzZVVVLbJYnKgZjtYC6jMCqNSvUwt0wtKAaAwLEI6u_1ggaCgoICAESBPPvU5sM&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=UbuyVI_rB4OYyQSliID4BQ&ved=0CCwQsw4&q=license%20plate) that you could use as your template.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The thing is I don't have to do the OCR part. What I have to do is from images like the one in the first link I provided I need to get to images like the ones in the second link I provided. No OCR

Comment: Better said: How can I extract only the white part of the image and  how can I rotate it in order to get to an image like the ones you provided in the link?

Comment: Going through OCR is a MUCH MUCH MUCH better way than trying to develop some kind of image processor that will take removing any skew/radix/perspective and turn that into a "readable" image.  OCR software, on the other hand, does exactly that but with information, not image manipulation.

Comment: Yes, but the thing is this is a project that needs to be done by two people. The first one(me) has to give the second only the licence plate from any sorts of images and the second one has to use OCR. This is what the professor asked...

Comment: I would start with grabbing the set of flattened EU license plates [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_registration_plates_of_Europe), using an image editor to strip out all of the actual text  Then you should be able to find some code that does image comparison, to determine which license plate to hand over to the OCR guy.